# How to connect from Delphi to Sybase Sql Server?

Tags: delphi, sybase

How can I connect from Delphi to Sybase ASE? I want to be able to make querys, execute stored procedures, reference views, etc., all the things that the server allows me to do.

Are there any components (like the dbGo components) or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

We tested [AnyDAC](http://www.anydac.net) with Sybase SQL Anywhere and Adaptive Server - works just great ! But finally we decided to go with AnyDAC and Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sybase odbc drivers](http://www.sybase.com/products/archivedproducts/odbc) or [nativedb](http://www.nativedb.com/).

Comment: +1 for NativeDB - using it here with Delphi 5 in both a legacy desktop app and a legacy service, and later this year we'll be dragging the whole lot up into Delphi 2007 (which NativeDB also supports). It's not too expensive for what it is, really, and in my experience it's damn fast!

Answer (score 0):

I always have a look at [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The dbGo components should work fine, it will work with any database as long as there is a suitable ADO driver for it.

The other data connnection component that come with Delphi, dbExpress, also has Sybase drivers available to download.